# How to parse a date with momentjs?

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs

I'm trying to parse a date in `momentjs`, in particular this is my goal:

> Ven Nov 13 2015 09:00:00

Now I'm using FullCalendar and when I get the `.start` date it's returned this:

> Fri Nov 13 2015 00:00:00

how you can see in my bottom code, I'm format the `calendarDateStartTemp` to `utc` for remove the GMT. In the next step, I transform the object in `italian` timezone, but this seems not working. Anyway, I've in `workingPlan[selDayName].start` the hour to edit, in particular this is the value: `09:00:00`, see the code:

```
var calendarDateStartTemp = $calendar.fullCalendar('getView').start;
                        var calendarDateStart = moment(calendarDateStartTemp).utc().format("ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss");

var calendarDateEnd = moment.lang('it');

calendarDateEnd = moment(moment(calendarDateStart).format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' '
                                    + workingPlan[selDayName].start).format('ddd, D MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss');
```

now the problem's that I get this result:

> Fri, 13 Nov 2015 09:00:00

instead of this:

> Ven Nov 13 2015 09:00:00

how you can see the date returned is in english language, but I don't know why `moment.lang` now working. I say that it's deprecated so I've also tried with `moment.locale` but I've the same problem. How I can fix this?

***NB: the language is italian***

Comment: Post some code for us to see **how** you've implemented i18n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = moment().locale('it').format('llll');
alert(data);
```

By default, Moment.js comes with English locale strings. If you need other locales, you can load them into Moment.js.

I'm assuming you have both moment.js and monement+locales.js included, the scripts are found here. http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I've inserted this line at the top of my script and I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: moment.locale(...).format is not a function

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, won't that ( *.. is not a function* ) mean that `moment` is returning `undefined` or `null` on *some* code paths?

Comment: i'm thinking he may not have the locales js file included.

Comment: I've updated moment.js I've now this result: Ven, 13 nov 2015 09:00:00 how I can get this: Ven Nov 13 2015 09:00:00?